# Writing SQL row statements inside each other more efficiently

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database

```
$res = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"], "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=5");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

        $firstName = $row['firstName'];

        $otherRes = mysqli_query($GLOBALS["___mysqli_ston"],
        "SELECT * FROM othertable WHERE firstName='$firstName'");

        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($otherRes)) {

             //SQL statements going off in here
        }
}
```

I've written the above example code to show the way I've been accessing tables with data from another table in SQL.

I've been learning my PHP skills with youtube and I'm sure there's a more efficient way of writing this, with dots between the table names and column names in SQL, but I can't figure out how it's supposed to be written.

Please can someone show me how they'd write the above code in the best, most efficient way? The real code using this method has started using a lot of data and taking a lot longer to finish than it needs to.

Thank you!

Comment: please take a look on `SQL Injection` on google, because your `firstName='$firstName'"` may lead to some problem if a user call himself `'; DROP TABLE users ;--`

Answer (score 0):

You could execute a single query  using a join

```
  SELECT * 
  FROM users 
  INNER JOIN othertable on  othertable.firstName= users.firstname
  WHERE user.id=5
```

(using inner you get only the row that have the same first name for of user with id =5)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there is a link between the two tables you would typically do a `join` using that common column like:

```
select * from othertable o
    left outer join users u on u.userid=o.userid
    where u.id=5
```

The above assumes there is a common column called `userid` in both tables